# Can carbohydrates in powdered form provide a more 'energy efficient' alternative solution to traditional combustion engines?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering

In my high school chemistry class I am studying the affect of surface area over the rate of reaction. In this case, using *Collision Theory* to describe how a high surface area to volume ratio contributes to a greater chance of particles colliding, which leads to more successful collisions per second; given reactants are at room temperature and other variables constant.

Since flour grains (in fine powdered form) is highly flammable through combustion with oxygen and may even explode when particles that are suspended in the air are ignited, could it offer a more energy efficient method of converting from chemical to kinetic energy through a combustion engine? I was thinking that due to flour's high air to fuel character and that it's

> 35 times more combustible than coal dust.

Would it be possible for the expanding combustion gas to push the piston, which in turn rotates the crankshaft and drives the engine?

I am aware that the mechanical components behind this ['flour driven engine'](https://patents.google.com/patent/CN202811062U/en) may not be similar to the traditional combustion engine. However, would the mechanics behind this design be realistic or probable in the future, if so, how might it look like? For example in the form of an air cylinder? What is the air to fuel ratio of four in comparison to volatilised fuel?

Comment: This looks like a ['Novel Idea' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/1832). Such questions tend to become moving targets and lead to discussions, neither of which are a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Comment: "*high surface area to volume ratio*" Wouldn't this be highest for *vaporised* diesel / gasoline / natural gas / propane / butane which is literally a collection of single fuel molecules suspended in air ? How can flour beat that type of area to volume ratio ?

Comment: Look how solid fuel rockets work and their disadvantages. Also look at what coal power plants do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to ignore molecular collisions, etc. and stick to the empirical world, which is where we engineers excel.

Energy content of flour is 353 Kcal/100g.  This equals 1.477 MJ/100g

Energy content of gasoline is 46.5  MJ/kg, or 4.65 MJ/100g

So, what this tells us is that gasoline has a much higher energy density than flour.  In practical terms, this means that a "flour engine" would need to be much physically larger to get the same work out if it.  A larger engine is unlikely to be more efficient.

This ignores the practical implications of feeding an engine with an aerosol flour charge.  People have tried this with coal for quite a while and have been generally unsuccessful.  Coal-water slurry combustion can work, but you have the problem of having to boil off the water, which doesn't help efficiency, and with pollution controls, which are all harder with coal.

Now, *efficiency* means getting the most work out of a device relative to the energy put into it.  Given the 100 years of regular fossil fuel engine development, we'll be at quite a disadvantage in getting our Flour Engine up to an equivalent efficiency.  Given all the infrastructure in place to move & store fossil fuels, moving flour around to do the same thing seems like a waste anyway.

The last issue is that moving food production into energy production is terrible for society, resulting in higher food costs.  People need food more than transportation.  Attempts to make this happen (like with ethanol) are driven by the farm lobby, not by good policy.

So my answer is, maybe you could get it to work, but **why would you want to?**